# Spring Boot Devtools hot reload not working in VS Code

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-devtools

I'm making an app with Spring Boot in VS Code but I cannot get hot reload to work.

WSL Ubuntu on Windows 11
Spring Boot version 3.2.2
Maven build
spring-boot-devtools added to pom.xml file
Java autobuild enabled

I have a REST Controller and when I edit the Controller.java file, the project does not automatically build again. I have tried running the project with doing run java on the main application or using the mvnw file. Both fail.

Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Enable automatic building in Intellij **or** force a project rebuild from the project menbu.